# Get distinct emails from semi colon separated string

Tags: plsql

I have three tables in plsql TBL_A,TBL_B and TBL_C, I have email column in each table and have multiple values in that column separated by ';', I want to combine DISTINCT email values from all 3 tables and store it in TBL_D, table structure is as below

Have tried LISTAGG but i am confused about getting DISTINCT values.

```
TBL_A : Email(Varchar2(500)) : abc@test.com;xyz@test;com;pqr@test;com (sample data)

TBL_B : Email(Varchar2(500)) : cba@test.com;zyx@test;com;pqr@test;com (sample data)

TBL_C : Email(Varchar2(500)) : abc@test.com;xyz@test;com;pqr@test;com;klm@test.com (sample data)
```

Want to get result like

```
  'abc@test.com;xyz@test.com;pqr@test.com;cba@test.com;zyx@test.com;klm@test.com'
```

and store it in EMAIL Column of Table D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with regex and listagg function:

```
insert into tbl_d
      select listagg(emails.email, ';') within group(order by emails.email)
        from (select regexp_substr(a.email, '[^;]+', 1, level) email
                from tbl_a a
              connect by regexp_substr(a.email, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null
              union
              select regexp_substr(a.email, '[^;]+', 1, level) email
                from tbl_b a
              connect by regexp_substr(a.email, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null
              union
              select regexp_substr(a.email, '[^;]+', 1, level) email
                from tbl_c a
              connect by regexp_substr(a.email, '[^;]+', 1, level) is not null) emails
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an alternative solution to @[tso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7953189/tso)'s also using regex and listagg function:

first you do union all, than Splitting the values into rows and aggregate as last

```
with tab1 as(
  select 'abc@test.com;xyz@test;com;pqr@test;com' as email from dual
)
,
tab2 as(
  select 'cba@test.com;zyx@test;com;pqr@test;com' as email from dual
)
,tab3 as(
  select 'abc@test.com;xyz@test;com;pqr@test;com;klm@test.com' as email from dual
)

select listagg(str,';')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) "emails"
from (
  SELECT distinct trim(regexp_substr(email, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
  from(
    select email
    from tab1
    union all
    select email
    from tab2
    union all
    select email
    from tab3
  )CONNECT BY instr(email, ';', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
)
```